# Bootstrap collapse event triggered twice for nested button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap `collapse` element that contains multiple other `collapse` elements, when a `collapse` is clicked (shown or hidden) I want to capture that event.

The problem that I am having is that the `collapse` event gets fired twice if the nested collapse button is clicked (for the parent collapse and the clicked collapse).

Here's is demo that shows the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/6nbsp9c1/2/

When the nested button is clicked the event gets triggered twice, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the jQuery [stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) method:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('event triggered');
});
```

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
> parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/v8h2bo51/1/).

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [stopImmediatePropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) to make sure the event is not getting called multiple times.

> The `stopImmediatePropagation()` method of the Event interface prevents other listeners of the same event from being called.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(document).on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', '.collapse', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //use this
  console.log('event triggered');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Link with href
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    test test test
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
      Link with href
    </a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
      <div class="card card-body">
        test test test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```